# Why doesn't my style get set on the child of a ContentControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I have the following XAML code for WPF

```
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="selections:EntitySelector">
                <Setter 
                    Property="EntitySelectorManager" 
                    Value="{Binding  SelectorManager, Mode=OneWay }"/>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Binding Path="Editor" />
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
```

Then in code behind in response to some event I have set the Editor propety

```
    this.Editor = element
```

where element is a control that contains one or more **EntitySelector** objects. However once the control is instantiated in the visual tree I can see that the binding has not worked.

First I check the **SelectorManager** property on the **DataContext** at the level of the **ContentControl**. This seems in order

[image]

Now I go into the **ContentControl** and see if any of the **EntitySelector** controls have their **EntitySelectorManager** properties set.

[image]

You can see that there is a binding expression but the result is Null. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but I don't really like it. Using a dynamic resource that is initialized from codebehind

```
public WeinCamWindow(WeinCamWorkPiece camViewModel)
{
    ViewModel = camViewModel;
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = ViewModel;
    this.Resources["EntitySelectionManager"] = ViewModel.SelectorManager;

}
```

and in the style use a dynamic resource

```
<Style TargetType="selections:EntitySelector">
    <!-- 'EntitySelectionManager' is set in code behind. -->
    <Setter Property="EntitySelectorManager"
            Value="{DynamicResource EntitySelectionManager}" />
</Style>
```

The dyamic resource propogates where all the other tricks I tried didn't work.